# Trouble installing SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Whenever I try to install SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

I have tried both version (32-bit/64-bit) and re-downloaded multiple times.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: On what version of Windows are you trying to install this? (Please be specific.)

Comment: @GordThompson Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have .Net framework 4 installed at your machine. If not - download it and install it and then try again with SQL Server.

Also check this [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632812/dotnetfx40-full-x86-x64-exe-install-fails#details) at Microsoft site about .Net framework 4 (there is workaround explained in the bug).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I just downloaded and installed `SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe` from [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29062) on a vanilla Win7Pro/64 VirtualBox virtual machine and encountered no errors.

### Edit

I also installed `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` from that same location on an older Vista machine. The SQL Server installer told me that it needed some new .NET components, then it proceeded to download and install them. I didn't need to manually install anything ahead of time.

**Also perhaps worth noting:**

Both of the machines on which my installs were successful had no anti-virus software installed. (They are development boxes behind a firewall and I don't do email or web surfing on them.)

Comment: I'm going to guess the OP's issue was a corrupted download.